# Exception raised when try to run web application using postgres database

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, redhat, c3p0, postgresql-9.4

when I run start.bat file of tomcat on linux with postgres database. It gives following error after changed in postgres_hba.conf file.

```
           C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2u13c99u1fd86im176rze7|779becbd]-HelperThread-#1--WARN -com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool:com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@1de8b573 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
```

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Answer (score -1):

The error message is fairly clear. You have tried to open more database connections than you have configured in `postgresql.conf`. Even the shortest search of your logs and the manuals would have made this clear.

Comment: How can I open more database connections?as I already changed the max_connection in the config file of postgres.

Comment: If you had done so you would have posted some evidence, wouldn't you? It would be really unhelpful to hide information while expecting people to help you.